# Accessing subitems in api gateway response mapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, xpath, mapping, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I'm trying to do a mapping in an api gateway and I can't manage to access the children objects inside the returned json. This is my case:

When I test the endpoint directly in the api gateway I get this response:

```
{
  "status": "FAIL",
  "output": {
    "errorCode": "my code",
    "message": "my message"
  }
}
```

And the api gateway integration response mapping is as follows:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path("$.output"))
$inputRoot
```

But I just want to return the json inside the `output` key, so I tried the following:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path("$.output"))
$inputRoot.output
```

And when I run it a get `no data`.

Before the transformation, the return value is

```
{
  "output":"{\"status\":\"FAIL\",\"output\":{\"errorCode\":\"my code\",\"message\":\"my message\"}}"
}
```

I think that the fact that is returned as string might have something to do, but I've tried with `$util.parseJson` and `$util.escapeJavaScript` and I had no luck.

Does anyone know how can I solve this? I can't change the integration response, I have to do it through the api gateway mapping.

Answer (score 0):

It should be JSON-like:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path("$.output"))
{
    "output": "$inputRoot"
}
```